# Converting free form english text to spanish, what are the options?

Tags: localization, translation

I have an application that will be used by spanish speaking people as well as english speaking people. I am using .resx files and localization to translate all the hard coded text. I am also retrieving language specific data from the database for some things that don't change often like "Category Descriptions". Here is my question. I think I already know the answer. Is there a way to translate free form text entered by a user? For example can a string entered as saved to a database in english be displayed in spanish? One more issue is these strings often contain engineering terms and technical abbreviations that I don't think could be translated with something like google translate. Is there anything else out there?  I am thinking that this text can only be translated by a human with knowledge of the terminolgy and abbreviations used in this particular industry.

Comment: What technology stack are you using?

Comment: I have an answer from my users. Have the users enter the strings in both English and Spanish and store them to the database. Display the correct strings based on the language of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are some online services such as Google Translate as pointed to by Binary Worrier. However, one should bear in mind that none of these services give accurate translations. Because, as you wrote, translation is a very difficult matter. Current obstacles to good automated translation include, as you wrote, lack of context.

This is a problem even for human translators. Ask a translator for a given sentence in another language. She'll answer: "Ok, what do you mean by this word: X or Y ? In which context ? Who are you talking to? Is this a formal or informal tone? etc...

This is especially true regarding localization where texts are usually very short. This increases the lack of context. Think of a simple menu item: "Load". Is it a name? Is it a verb? Damn, even a human translator needs more information. So don't expect a computer to solve the problem.

Of course, it all depends on the accuracy that you need and the acceptance factor of your users for bad translations. Google Translate et al are very successful because people prefer a bad translation than nothing.

If I were you, I'd make a few manual tests with typical texts in your DBs and see if the translation accuracy fits your needs.

BTW, I believe Google Translate is free for reasonable of amount of use. Basically, unless you want to translate the whole Wikipedia every week, you should be on the safe side ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into [Google Translate APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_translate.html) and translate this stuff on the fly, I think there's a charge though

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer from my users. Have the users enter the strings in both English and Spanish and store them to the database. Display the correct strings based on the language of the browser. I still have alot of grunt work to do with filling out the .resx files and modifying all the words I need translated.